# give color to intersections between rectangles and ellipse in R

Tags: r, colors, intersection, rectangles, ellipse

I want to give colors to the different intersections of an ellipse with several rectangles which do not overlap. Here is the graph:

```
library(plotrix)
library(latex2exp)

plot(NULL,xlim=c(-10,15),ylim=c(-11,12.5),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")
rect(-10,-11,15,12,lwd=1.5)
segments(-10,0,5,0)
segments(5,-11,5,12)
segments(-3,-11,-3,0)

segments(5,2,15,2)


draw.ellipse(2.5,0,11,8,border=2)

text(-9.8,12.9,"U",col=1,cex=1.5)

text(-7,8,expression('A'[1]),col=1,cex=1.5)
text(10,9.5,expression('A'[2]),col=1,cex=1.5)
text(10,-8,expression('A'[3]),col=1,cex=1.5)
text(-1,-9.7,expression('A'[4]),col=1,cex=1.5)
text(-8,-6,expression('A'[5]),col=1,cex=1.5)

text(0,10,"B",col=2,cex=1.5)

text(-.5,4,TeX("$A_1 \\bigcap B$"),col=4,cex=1.2)
text(7.2,4,TeX("$A_2 \\bigcap B$"),col=4,cex=1.2)
text(7.2,-4,TeX("$A_3 \\bigcap B$"),col=4,cex=1.2)
text(-.6,-3,TeX("$A_4 \\bigcap B$"),col=4,cex=1.2)
text(-5.5,-2.5,TeX("$A_5 \\bigcap B$"),col=4,cex=1.2)
```

[image: output image of the code above]

For each one of the $A_i \cap B$ areas I want to give them different colors or shading.